# asp.net mvc editing Membership User data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

What is the best approach to allow a user to change his email address?

im using the built in membership provider and AccountController. in asp.net mvc 3

My app is using Entity Framework but im not sure if its correct to add that membershipUser to the edmx and create a UsersController to do this... or add an action to accountController that handles this.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

The membership provider has the ability to help you manage that.  You would most likely add the ability into your `AccountController` to do this.  I wouldn't add it into your EF classes.  It is handled outside of your database anyway (unless you've written a custom `MembershipProvider` to talk to tables inside your database).

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200167/admin-pages-to-manage-asp-net-membership-provider-role-management) question too as it addresses some of what you may want to do and it includes source code.